# AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory doesn`t work when solution is under program files (x86)

Tags: c#

Trying to get solution path, below works fine on my system but failes when on VMs since the path is located under "C:\Program Files (x86)".

```
string FullFilePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"File.txt");
```

Path returned from the above is 'C:\Program Files x86\Temp\SolutionFolder'

If you notice that it doesn't have common brackets - 'C:\Program Files x86' which doesn't exist. What`s wrong with my code?

Comment: Aren't ["braces"](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/JavaSyntax/parentheses.html) these: `{`, `}`?

Comment: He means the brackets.

Comment: Does `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)` work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure that is wrong there, but could you try [Environment.CurrentDirectory Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)?